# mariadb group by slow on small subset

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mariadb

I want to group a subset of a fairly large table using this query on mariadb:

#### Q1

```
SELECT count(item_group_id) 
FROM item 
WHERE created > [-1 DAY] 
GROUP BY item_group_id
```

The subset of `created > [-1 DAY]` is only about 200 rows. The entire set of table `item` has **over half a million** rows.

The query takes over **9 Seconds!**

Without the `GROUPY BY` the query takes 40ms!

This is confusing to me as I thought the `GROUP BY` statement should be applied **AFTER** the `WHERE` statement.

So I try a different query, to force mariadb to apply the `GROUP BY` only on the subset of 200 rows:

#### Q2

```
SELECT count(item_group_id) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM item WHERE created > [-1 DAY]) t 
GROUP BY item_group_id
```

Still, Q2 Gives me the exact same behaviour as Q1....

***Funny enough, Q3 worked and reduced execution time from 9s to 100ms:***

#### Q3

```
SELECT count(item_group_id) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM item WHERE created > [-1 DAY] LIMIT 100000000) t 
GROUP BY item_group_id
```

---

#### Explain for Q2

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len | ref  |  rows  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY |     108 | NULL | 643167 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

#### Explain for Q3

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 643207 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| 2  | DERIVED     | item       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 643207 |                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Using the `LIMIT [large number]` did exactly what I wanted and created the temp table **before** applying the `GROUP BY`

What exactly is the `LIMIT` doing to make mariadb behave differently? Can anyone explain this please?

cheers!

Edit: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
  `item_group_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
  `content_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
  `section_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
  `person_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:uuid)',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D4707EBD57B8F0DE` (`item_group_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D4707EBDD07ECCB6` (`content_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D4707EBDF639F774` (`section_id`),
  KEY `IDX_D4707EBD9395C3F3` (`person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D4707EBD57B8F0DE` FOREIGN KEY (`item_group_id`) REFERENCES `item_group` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D4707EBD9395C3F3` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `pseron` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D4707EBDD07ECCB6` FOREIGN KEY (`content_id`) REFERENCES `content` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_D4707EBDF639F774` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to see the indexes, engine, and other things.

Comment: @RickJames I've added the show create. Thank You.

Comment: Generating the temp table was costly; sorting it was costly; it may be caching that led to the more complex query being faster.  Run both flavors twice; report the times.  (Caching is a big factor in speed differences.)

Comment: `CHAR(36)` -- smells like a UUID; are they?  How big (GB) is the table?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Yup Uuid. Also, innodb_buffer_pool_size : 134217728. The Table is only about 230mb (650 000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

There's no index on `created`, so the `WHERE` clause can't be optimized, hence a full table scan.  Add this:

```
INDEX(created, item_group_id)
```

UUIDs are terribly bad for performance once the table becomes bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  This is due the the severe randomness of UUIDs, leading to the cache being useless and queries being seriously I/O-dependent.

**More**

The 'Rows' numbers in `EXPLAIN` are not necessarily correct, sometimes not even close.  Let's research it further.  Do the following with each variant of the query:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

This will provide *actual* counts of how many rows were touched.  It is usually a good metric for comparing two competing queries.

The real problem is the randomness of the UUIDs.

- Assuming you have at least 4GB of RAM, change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `600M`.  What you have is probably thrashing the disk.  This, alone, will probably bring the time down from 9 seconds to 1.
- Consider using something other than UUIDs.
- `utf8` is unnecessary for hex strings.
- It is possible to shrink UUIDs to `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes) from the current size of 36 (or perhaps 108, due to utf8), thereby shrinking the size of the data and the indexes.  This is another way to cut back on I/O.  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Comment: Column `a` is `item_group_id` (updated the question). Also this doesnt really answer my question. I have no problems without the GROUP BY. The plain WHERE query is blazing fast. I just don't understand that mariadb is somehow applying the GROUP BY to the whole table...

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB?  See what I added to my Answer; it is likely provide a solution and a way to dig deeper in case the fix(es) are not sufficient.